# Hadoop always finishes with java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, hadoop, timeout

I am new to Hadoop and I have written a couple of jobs that always end with this no matter what:

```
    WARN util.ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:67)
```

I am running this on a Mac (Sierra 10.12.6) and I have installed Hadoop using homebrew.

This even happens when running the wordcount example from the hadoop docs.

Its odd because I don't get any errors while it is processing and I get the output I expect.

Just wondered if anyone has run into the same issue and if there is any extra configuration I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hello @paras, no I was not able to resolve this. It was for a university project that has long been completed so I haven't invested any more time to solve this issue

Comment: thanks for your reply. I haven't been able to resolve this either. Waiting for someone to shed some light!

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout for the Hadoop Job Shutdown hook is 30 seconds. You can change this timeout by configuring `hadoop.service.shutdown.timeout` in `core-site.xml`.

You can find the code related to this timeout in the `ShutdownHookManager` Class.

```
 static long getShutdownTimeout(Configuration conf) {
    long duration = conf.getTimeDuration("hadoop.service.shutdown.timeout", 30L, TIME_UNIT_DEFAULT);
    if (duration < 1L) {
      duration = 1L;
    }

    return duration;
  }
```